# Zero sum covers

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

### Introduction

Consider a nonempty list **L** of integers.
A *zero-sum slice* of **L** is a contiguous subsequence of **L** whose sum equals 0.
For example, **[1, -3, 2]** is a zero-sum slice of **[-2, 4, 1, -3, 2, 2, -1, -1]**, but **[2, 2]** is not (because it doesn't sum to 0), and neither is **[4, -3, -1]** (because it's not contiguous).

A collection of zero-sum slices of **L** is a *zero-sum cover* of **L** if every element belongs to at least one of the slices.
For example:

```
L = [-2, 4, 1, -3, 2, 2, -1, -1]
A = [-2, 4, 1, -3]
B =        [1, -3, 2]
C =                  [2, -1, -1]
```

The three zero-sum slices **A**, **B** and **C** form a zero-sum cover of **L**.
Multiple copies of the same slice can appear in a zero-sum cover, like this:

```
L = [2, -1, -1, -1, 2, -1, -1]
A = [2, -1, -1]
B =        [-1, -1, 2]
C =                [2, -1, -1]
```

Of course, not all lists have a zero-sum cover; some examples are **[2, -1]** (every slice has nonzero sum) and **[2, 2, -1, -1, 0, 1]** (the leftmost **2** is not part of a zero-sum slice).

### The task

Your input is a nonempty integer list **L**, taken in any reasonable format.
Your output shall be a truthy value if **L** has a zero-sum cover, and a falsy value if not.

You can write a full program or a function, and the lowest byte count wins.

### Test cases

```
[-1] -> False
[2,-1] -> False
[2,2,-1,-1,0,1] -> False
[2,-2,1,2,-2,-2,4] -> False
[3,-5,-2,0,-3,-2,-1,-2,0,-2] -> False
[-2,6,3,-3,-3,-3,1,2,2,-2,-5,1] -> False
[5,-8,2,-1,-7,-4,4,1,-8,2,-1,-3,-3,-3,5,1] -> False
[-8,-8,4,1,3,10,9,-11,4,4,10,-2,-3,4,-10,-3,-5,0,6,9,7,-5,-3,-3] -> False
[10,8,6,-4,-2,-10,1,1,-5,-11,-3,4,11,6,-3,-4,-3,-9,-11,-12,-4,7,-10,-4] -> False
[0] -> True
[4,-2,-2] -> True
[2,2,-3,1,-2,3,1] -> True
[5,-3,-1,-2,1,5,-4] -> True
[2,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1] -> True
[-2,4,1,-3,2,2,-1,-1] -> True
[-4,-1,-1,6,3,6,-5,1,-5,-4,5,3] -> True
[-11,8,-2,-6,2,-12,5,3,-7,4,-7,7,12,-1,-1,6,-7,-4,-5,-12,9,5,6,-3] -> True
[4,-9,12,12,-11,-11,9,-4,8,5,-10,-6,2,-9,10,-11,-9,-2,8,4,-11,7,12,-5] -> True
```

Comment: By "every element belongs to one of the slices", are you treating the same value at different indices as distinct?

Comment: @ngenisis Yes, they are distinct and each should occur in a slice that contains the corresponding index.

Comment: Should not the third falsy example `[2,2,-1,-1,0,1] -> False` be truthy since both slices `[2,-1,-1]` and `[-1,0,1]` add to zero and all their elements are in the original list?

Comment: The leftmost 2 is not part of any zero-sum slice. It's a bit unclear, but they have to occur in a slice that "contains their index".

Comment: Understood. That makes it harder. :o)

Answer (score 13):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
JẆịS¥ÐḟċþJḄẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ZVFLTsMwEN33FD3AWIp/iXMCpG5ZVrkMQrDohhvAhh0HqFqJBeEi4SLhzbMdXBFN/Jl582bmeT0sl6flerr/ep9flvPr92n@PCznx@Xyts7PPw8fsLt1Pe72@I7GTpJPTtqz3tQ6aQFOrHCDher3YqI6OjGeMVturiJw7cUzTFOSTBP/6MGRStlBTJAA2OapmQ0eMZiiQNjJCJwVpnWk9jgam5uKaKcHZGCrylRZAEgIoR47x7haNpKMFNh7pgSuuYyxTh1DLhCm3ST7ImhXmTOju5FUR4fX30zti2IW05nQPkexcmzUpDZe3L9QKCkqd095OUwA9TayDpDYXM98p0EVPegyiHUbSX4JyuEgX6QUzYCjgom3/EeFJ51DdSH9yPfQ@Kg1E1/FljIRyv0C)

#### How it works

```
JẆịS¥ÐḟċþJḄẠ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

J             Yield all indices of A.
 Ẇ            Window; yield all slices of indices.
     Ðḟ       Filter; keep slices for which the link to the left returns 0.
    ¥           Combine the two atoms to the left into a dyadic chain.
  ị               Retrieve the elements of A at the slice's indices.
   S              Take the sum.
         J    Yield the indices of A.
       ċþ     Count table; count how many times each index appears in each table.
          Ḅ   Unbinary; convery the array of counts of each index from base 2 to 
              integer. This yields 0 iff an index does not appear in any slice.
           Ạ  All; return 1 iff all integers are non-zero.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Mathematica, <s>66</s> 65 bytes

*Saved 1 byte, and hopefully learned a new trick for the future, thanks to ngenisis!*

Two equally long alternatives, both of which are unnamed functions taking a list of integers as input and returning `True` or `False`:

```
And@@Table[0==Product[Tr@#[[i;;j]],{i,k},{j,k,l}],{k,l=Tr[1^#]}]&

0==Norm@Table[Product[Tr@#[[i;;j]],{i,k},{j,k,l}],{k,l=Tr[1^#]}]&
```

In both cases, `Tr@#[[i;;j]]` computes the sum of the slice of the input from position `i` to position `j` (1-indexed). `Product[...,{i,k},{j,k,l}]` multiples together all these slice-sums, as `i` ranges over indices that are at most `k` and `j` ranges over indices that are at least `k`. (Note that `l=Tr[1^#]` defines `l` to be the sum of `1` to all the powers in the input list, which is simply the length of the list.) In other words, this product equals 0 if and only if the `k`th element belongs to a zero-sum slice.

In the first version, each of those products is compared to `0`, and `And@@` returns `True` precisely when every single product equals `0`. In the second version, the list of products is acted upon by the function `Norm` (the length of the `l`-dimensional vector), which equals `0` if and only if every entry equals `0`.

Comment: `Tr[1^#]` saves `1` byte from `Length@#`.

Comment: Would `0^` work instead of `0==`? Not sure how Mathematica handles that. (you would return `1`/`0` instead of `true`/`false`)

Comment: Cool idea, but Mathematica returns `Indeterminate` for `0^0`. Also, `1`/`0` aren't actually truthy/falsy in Mathematica—it's too strongly typed to make golfers happy :)

Answer (score 7):

### Mathematica, <s>65</s> 64 bytes

*Thanks to ngenisis for saving 1 byte.*

```
Union@@Cases[Subsequences[x=Range@Tr[1^#]],a_/;Tr@#[[a]]==0]==x&
```

I'd rather find a pure pattern matching solution, but it's proving to be tricky (and things like `{___,a__,___}` are always super lengthy).

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, 94 bytes

```
import Data.Lists
g x=(1<$x)==(1<$nub(id=<<[i|(i,0)<-fmap sum.unzip<$>powerslice(zip[1..]x)]))
```

Usage example: `g [-11,8,-2,-6,2,-12,5,3,-7,4,-7,7,12,-1,-1,6,-7,-4,-5,-12,9,5,6,-3]`
-> `True`.

How it works (let's use `[-1,1,5,-5]` for input):

```
        zip[1..]x  -- zip each element with its index
                   -- -> [(1,-1),(2,1),(3,5),(4,-5)]
      powerslice   -- make a list of all continuous subsequences
                   -- -> [[],[(1,-1)],[(1,-1),(2,1)],[(1,-1),(2,1),(3,5)],[(1,-1),(2,1),(3,5),(4,-5)],[(2,1)],[(2,1),(3,5)],[(2,1),(3,5),(4,-5)],[(3,5)],[(3,5),(4,-5)],[(4,-5)]]
    <$>            -- for each subsequence
   unzip           --   turn the list of pairs into a pair of lists
                   --   -> [([],[]),([1],[-1]),([1,2],[-1,1]),([1,2,3],[-1,1,5]),([1,2,3,4],[-1,1,5,-5]),([2],[1]),([2,3],[1,5]),([2,3,4],[1,5,-5]),([3],[5]),([3,4],[5,-5]),([4],[-5])]
  fmap sum         --   and sum the second element
                   --   -> [([],0),([1],-1),([1,2],0),([1,2,3],5),([1,2,3,4],0),([2],1),([2,3],6),([2,3,4],1),([3],5),([3,4],0),([4],-5)]
 [i|(i,0)<-    ]   -- take all list of indices where the corresponding sum == 0
                   -- -> [[],[1,2],[1,2,3,4],[3,4]]
 id=<<             -- flatten the list
                   -- -> [1,2,1,2,3,4,3,4]
nub                -- remove duplicates
                   -- -> [1,2,3,4]

(1<$x)==(1<$    )  -- check if the above list has the same length as the input list.
```

Comment: `powerslice` is such a great function name.

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>36</s> 35 bytes

```
#\*/@e.[:;]({:*0=[:+/{.)@|:\.\@,.#\
```

For every subsum I add the element's indexes and I keep the indexes iff subsum is `0` and then check whether every index is present.

Trick: 1-based indexes of a list can be generated with `#\` i.e. length of every prefix.

Usage:

```
   (#\*/@e.[:;]({:*0=[:+/{.)@|:\.\@,.#\) 2 _1 _1 2
1
   (#\*/@e.[:;]({:*0=[:+/{.)@|:\.\@,.#\) 2 _1
0
```

[Try it online here.](https://tio.run/nexus/j)

Comment: I think you can save 2 bytes using the base 1 trick for summation and using a composed flatten ``#\*/@e.&,]({:*0=1#.{.)@|:\.\@,.#\``

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to Bubbler*

```apl
∧/∨⌿↑0={×\⌽+\⌽⍵}¨,\⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVG9SgNBEO73Kaa7QoO3f3e3hW8SkIDEJqCtBDuJAXNBC/ERTCFYiKUI8U3mReL87F6SwoOZ2Zufb2a@mdzMRpe3k9n11Q6XD1NSb2e43ODqBxfP9fn893WMq@8TVth/3W03p2Ncv3Du7gIXT3Ps19UUH@@xf68oiv1nMtsPaxyoFitSg3odWFDLEownG@Vdk/Y5YgePM/xqwOeoCmMUlEjIjNAN3VqSAAHskXdfzRUcYeEswqshcZoFqasztKcf8pbJIk3UUGKbZxY0Q@GO3NwyD0@7Su@okIpDjybXhGxTiVsn3rY0C6Yala8y/zJdm9LSZa49KHM@c@IHLi1EAd5fhGX4E5aVMQ/uyB@GbL5Co4zn7QKheiNbdHmURosdR@QWQXQL1h0AlSNlkhyxGpUf2SlxthZYVUnSO9lCONI@SY8lWUkm6PRmtnSMfw)

#### Explanation

```apl
                 ,\⎕      ⍝ All prefixes of the input 
       {       }¨         ⍝ Map each to
          ⌽+\⌽⍵           ⍝ The sum of each postfix 
        ×\                ⍝ Scan multiplied, spreading any zero sums to the other elements in the sub-array
     0=                   ⍝ Map zeroes to true
    ↑                     ⍝ Mix the arrays into a 2D matrix
∧/∨⌿                      ⍝ Do all columns have at least one true value?
```

Comment: Please don't use Dyalog Classic unless you really have to.

Comment: @Adám Yeah, I've read through the reasons not to and I'm using Unicode for future answers.

Comment: [A full program](https://tio.run/##dVG9SgNBEO73Kaa7QoO3f3e3hW8SkIDEJqCtBDuJAXNBC/ERTCFYiKUI8U3mReL87F6SwoOZ2Zufb2a@mdzMRpe3k9n11Q6XD1NSb2e43ODqBxfP9fn893WMq@8TVth/3W03p2Ncv3Du7gIXT3Ps19UUH@@xf68oiv1nMtsPaxyoFitSg3odWFDLEownG@Vdk/Y5YgePM/xqwOeoCmMUlEjIjNAN3VqSAAHskXdfzRUcYeEswqshcZoFqasztKcf8pbJIk3UUGKbZxY0Q@GO3NwyD0@7Su@okIpDjybXhGxTiVsn3rY0C6Yala8y/zJdm9LSZa49KHM@c@IHLi1EAd5fhGX4E5aVMQ/uyB@GbL5Co4zn7QKheiNbdHmURosdR@QWQXQL1h0AlSNlkhyxGpUf2SlxthZYVUnSO9lCONI@SY8lWUkm6PRmtnSMfw) saves 2 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 81 bytes

[Try it online](https://repl.it/FEqo)

Simplistic brute-force solution; for every element of the array, try to find a zero-sum slice that contains it.

```
->a{(0..l=a.size).all?{|i|(0..i).any?{|j|(i..l).any?{|k|a[j..k].inject(:+)==0}}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 109 bytes

```
f=([q,...a],b=[],c=[])=>1/q?f(a,[...b,0].map((x,i)=>x+q||(c=c.map((n,j)=>n|i<=j)),c.push(0)),c):c.every(x=>x)
```

#### Test snippet

```js
f=([q,...a],b=[],c=[])=>1/q?f(a,[...b,0].map((x,i)=>x+q||(c=c.map((n,j)=>n|i<=j)),c.push(0)),c):c.every(x=>x)

I.textContent = I.textContent.replace(/.+/g,x=>x+` (${f(eval(x.split(" ")[0]))})`)
```

```html
<pre id=I>[-1] -> False
[2,-1] -> False
[2,2,-1,-1,0,1] -> False
[2,-2,1,2,-2,-2,4] -> False
[3,-5,-2,0,-3,-2,-1,-2,0,-2] -> False
[-2,6,3,-3,-3,-3,1,2,2,-2,-5,1] -> False
[5,-8,2,-1,-7,-4,4,1,-8,2,-1,-3,-3,-3,5,1] -> False
[-8,-8,4,1,3,10,9,-11,4,4,10,-2,-3,4,-10,-3,-5,0,6,9,7,-5,-3,-3] -> False
[10,8,6,-4,-2,-10,1,1,-5,-11,-3,4,11,6,-3,-4,-3,-9,-11,-12,-4,7,-10,-4] -> False
[0] -> True
[4,-2,-2] -> True
[2,2,-3,1,-2,3,1] -> True
[5,-3,-1,-2,1,5,-4] -> True
[2,-1,-1,-1,2,-1,-1] -> True
[-2,4,1,-3,2,2,-1,-1] -> True
[-4,-1,-1,6,3,6,-5,1,-5,-4,5,3] -> True
[-11,8,-2,-6,2,-12,5,3,-7,4,-7,7,12,-1,-1,6,-7,-4,-5,-12,9,5,6,-3] -> True
[4,-9,12,12,-11,-11,9,-4,8,5,-10,-6,2,-9,10,-11,-9,-2,8,4,-11,7,12,-5] -> True</pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>123</s> 120 bytes

<sub>-3 bytes thanks to @Zgarb</sub>

Populates a list with the same size as the input with zero-sum slices and overwrites according to indexes, returning its equality to the original at the end.

```
def f(l):
 s=len(l);n=[0]*s
 for i in range(s):
  for j in range(i,s+1):
   if sum(l[i:j])==0:n[i:j]=l[i:j]
 return n==l
```

Comment: I think you can use `0` as the placeholder instead of `None`. There won't be false positives, because every `0` in the input is always part or a zero-sum slice.

Comment: You are right. I thought about that but ended up concluding that it could incur in false positives.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 22 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
≢={≢∪∊↓∘⍳/¨⍸∘.=⍨0,+\⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVE/S0NBDN/7KW7r4Kvev/dv6ORiJ8E6uhSkLgVdRZyEx7PwiiKCs1Nx6SCC8/so@SLPXJK71oPkcpfkl@SXxd1qcn2/WN3eDLB5n51D86IHeP6cPqCC9gvaNTRv0H5A933Sb6H7Rft4Ct1WZ0dX0P08DkvMgW4D66d@56B5RZz5xanC6/JsNh@WKut3ZrRUVsWbLBKtoscqI3cQj78OrZxeGrUTn0k/FmOCXVDkXoxUsJQf8ANKlaqWKF55Zf797vM5J/iChDjE1KoOgUZRphZ4hw/8jf3l2FeBgaV0TniIhQEVOkJZGQLnpvo5gzISGoVkebnr6DeWfstYzo/Gk3jGWCLTqCK8TSw7xXy5xINLHBp6@7iZJOkl/DJT7nBv5PEpI2ygYLZlJo/YjqKw@0raKhjABh/twZMulbEHUHFBQo5FPnPmRSasQzynGFY1JVQ0D7HDlWpeFEXV1EPF@zKxZv4H)

Same byte count as [Jo King's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/210922/78410), but totally different approach.

#### How it works

```apl
≢={≢∪∊↓∘⍳/¨⍸∘.=⍨0,+\⍵}  ⍝ Input: integer vector
  {             0,+\⍵}  ⍝ Cumulative sum and prepend 0
            ∘.=⍨        ⍝ Self outer product by equality
           ⍸            ⍝ Extract coords of ones; (a,b) with a>b is included
                        ⍝ iff the interval [b+1..a] has zero sum
      ↓∘⍳/¨  ⍝ For each coord, [b+1..a] if a>b, empty vector otherwise
   ≢∪∊       ⍝ Count unique values
≢=           ⍝ Is the count same as the length of the original array?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 49 bytes

```
% =>(1 to%.size)flatMap(%sliding)exists(_.sum==0)
```

#### [Try it at ideone](https://ideone.com/o0dk4z)

#### Usage:

```
val f:(Seq[Int]=>Boolean)= % =>(1 to%.size)flatMap(%sliding)exists(_.sum==0)
f(Seq(4, -2, -2)) //returns true
```

#### Ungolfed:

```
array=>(1 to array.size)
  .flatMap(n => array.sliding(n))
  .exists(slice => slice.sum == 0)
```

#### Explanation:

```
% =>            //define a anonymouns function with a parameter called %
  (1 to %.size) //create a range from 1 to the size of %
  flatMap(      //flatMap each number n of the range
    %sliding    //to an iterator with all slices of % with length n
  )exists(      //check whether there's an iterator with a sum of 0
    _.sum==0
  )
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how this works, but I think it should fail on some of the truthy test cases.

Comment: @Zgarb I added a link to ideone, so you can verify that it's correct. It's basically a brute-force, trying every possible slice.

Comment: You can use `%` as a parameter name? Cool!

Comment: @Cyoce You can use pretty much any Unicode char except `.,;:()[]{}\"'`. Pretty useful for golfing, because they get seperated from letters by the parse, so you can save some whitespace.

Comment: I checked the test cases, and it seems to give `true` for the second falsy case.

Comment: @Cyoce In fact, all of the operators in java are simply methods called `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `%`, `<` and so on of the Int / Float / Boolean classes.

Comment: @Zgarb I updated the ideone link to include the second testcase (`[2, -1]`). It returns true.

Comment: Welp, I meant the second falsy example in the text, which is actually the third falsy test case. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, 109 bytes

```
#(=(count %)(count(set(flatten(for[r[(range(count %))]l r p(partition l 1 r):when(=(apply +(map % p))0)]p))))
```

Generates all partitions which sum to zero, checks that it has "length of input vector" distinct indices.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 104 bytes

Brute force and still over 99 bytes. :-(

```php
for($p=$r=$c=$argc;$s=--$p;)for($i=$c;$s&&$k=--$i;)for($s=0;$k<$c&&($r-=!$s+=$argv[$k++])&&$s;);echo!$r;
```

takes input from command line arguments, `1` for truthy, empty for falsy. Run with `-r`.

**breakdown**

```php
for($p=$r=$argc;$s=$p--;)   # loop $p from $argc-1 to 0 with dummy value >0 for $s
    for($i=$p;$s&&$k=$i--;)     # loop $i (slice start) from $p to 1, break if sum is 0
        for($s=0;                   # init sum to 0
            $k<$argc                # loop $k (slice end) from $i to $argc-1
            &&($r-=!$s+=$argv[$k++])    # update sum, decrement $r if sum is 0
            &&$s;);                     # break loop if sum is 0
echo!$r;                    # $r = number of elements that are not part of a zero-sum slice
```

`$argv[0]` contains the filename; if run with `-r`, it will be `-` and evaluate to `0` for numeric ops.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 102 bytes

```
a=>(g=f=>a.map((_,i)=>f(i)))(i=>g(j=>j<i||(t+=a[j])||g(k=>b[k]&=k<i|k>j),t=0),b=g(_=>1))&&!/1/.test(b)
```

Computes the partial sums for all the elements `i..j` inclusive, and resets the relevant elements of `b` from `1` to `0` when it finds a zero sum, finally checking that there are no `1`s left.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 99 bytes

```python
lambda a,r=range:len({k for j in r(len(a)+1)for i in r(j)if sum(a[i:j])==0for k in r(i,j)})==len(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLbuowEN3zFd4Rq5Or2HmQIOXu2m033dEuTDElkCaRSe5tVfXb6cw4oIAqOQ/POXPOPLrPftc28WlbPp9q877eGGHAlc40b3ZZ2yb4Ooht68ReVI1wAUWMvFOSYpWP7WW1FcfhPTCrarl/kWUZEXrwaAV7@Y0xn3n6v6tqK57cYJcz0btPfCOvA9EOvSjpd@gD@efY1VUfzEX4V8wlUjpXNX2wDew/UwdIkhLE/Lhrh3oj1nbO6cizH6@268X948O9c61birWz5nBaheqFpB5MfbSzlYbbO0XoRHBL1KCAP3iSKRZDmFIwgjBmXI03PWVhKIOYKXxIzMul11aolY9lLCBMIEHqJXLOvslBHA8xUTiCArkKODViixh/Q@ULTLG0DCkLLpvUpkpIyhFGX@4Ex0D2KQuyDH4zTkv47a1CpSmw8CZX04n4QmuerbyonkR4BjQMBOKxJ4/42pSfe3oWPWf5JYXqvK8JSOsBLlb/hiZjIi0j4@Fzewl6xFMedpVzuRmraMJpIwm9FqD0RceviWekca4pz@e664L4nKL4KSgjp7ZoXuxQ8K4IL8g2542p0Sm9yP0A)

Creates a set of all indices which are part of a zero sum. Then checks if all indices are present.

Answer (score -1):

## Python, 86 Bytes

```
def f(l):
 r=range(len(l))
 if[i for i in r for j in r if sum(l[j:j+i+1])==0]:return 1
```

Truthy = 1
Falsy   = None

Comment: This incorrectly returns `1` for the third test case.

Comment: It actually returns `1` for all test cases except the first two falsy ones.